# W540 + 14.04 + nvidia driver = no work

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, thinkpad

there's a strange problem I cannot solve: there are two Lenovo W540 (A) and (B).
W540 has two graphics chips: intel and nvidia Quadro K1100M. There is no bios setting to disable intel, and/or only nvidia powers external display ports - so if you want to use extenal monitor you have to use nvidia. Now the problem is: *I was able to install and configure nvidia on (A), but I do fail using the same steps on (B)*

The first one (A) is mine. Installation steps:

1. 1  14.04  x86_64 installed, updated, installed xfce4 (I do not know
   if that matter, but no other work was made under unity),  2 enabled
   ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa ppa, installed  *nvidia-340*, and disabled
   edgers
2. xorg.conf created by `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
3. computer booted using nvidia but only 800x600 was available and nvidia-settings did not list any card, so I checked `sudo nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` and updated xorg.conf with Board Name and BusID, eg

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Nvidia"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K1100M"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection
```

after reboot HD resolution is available, external monitor works, nvidia-settings does recognize my card

(B) was installed exactly the same steps as above (also tried with other nvidia versions, eg those supplied with 14.04) but I wasn't able to made nvidia-settings to see card or wasn't able to get ANY correct display at all (blank screen after login or even just-after-boot). If I replace HDD between (A) and (B) - my installation works (so this is not hardware problem).

**My questions are:**
a) what config files should I compare/copy between those two systems to make them work the same
b) if there's no other option how to reliably clone drivers and configuration from (A) to (B)?

Comment: So both are running Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64, have the same Nvidia cards, and the same settings in BIOS?

Comment: Wilf: exactly: the same OS, arch, laptop, bios versions

Comment: Hint: Video card has some internal state settings that keep their values on reboot, they may make the difference. For example, it is a know problem that if wi-fi was turned off in Windows, you can't turn it on after reboot into Linux  no matter what you do. Same may go here.